# Sequelize pool monitoring with Prometheus

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, monitoring, prometheus, prom-client

I have a nodejs application which is using `sequelize` and `sequelize-pool` for connecting with database. I am working on enabling monitoring for this application.

I am using `prom-client` and collecting default set of metrics, which includes heap usage, etc.

I would like to monitor metrics like used connections, connection timeouts, etc. as well. I think we might be able to plug in a custom metric to be able to do that.

However, would like to know if there are any existing npm modules or patterns that I can leverage here.

Would appreciate any pointers on this. Thanks!